# net and vat amounts not equal to total

Tags: c#

The code below works but sometimes it is out by 0.01 as in the example below

How to ensure that the net values (amountA + amountB) plus vat will always  be equal to the total of wallet + gusset

```
        {
        this.transaction.NetValue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) / 1.2m + Convert.ToDecimal(gusset) / 1.2m, 2);  (5587.67)
        netAmountA = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) / 1.2m, 2);  (1126.28)
        netAmountB = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(gusset) / 1.2m, 2);  (4461.38)
        vatAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) + Convert.ToDecimal(gusset) - Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) / 1.2m + Convert.ToDecimal(gusset) / 1.2m, 2);
        }
```

vat amount is   1117.53

netAmountA  1126.28

netAmountB  4461.38

total       6705.19 (out by 0.01)

The total figure in this example is 6705.20 which is made up of

wallet = 5353.66

gusset = 1351.54

Answer (score 2):

Rounding two numbers then adding them can yield different results from rounding a summed number.

Think of it this way:

```
3.4 + 4.4 = 7.8
```

If you were to round up the `7.8` you would get `8`, but if you round `3.4` and `4.4` *first*, you would be adding `3 + 4` and get `7`.

Try rounding *after* you have summed the figures instead :)

Comment: I have no round up when doing the addition

Comment: Yes you are (but not in the code) :)  You are summing the rounded versions of netAmountA and netAmountB and getting 6705.19.  Don't round these values, add them together and what do you get?

Comment: You are referring to the first line ? If I remove the Math.Round bit on that line then I am unable to use /1.2m. Lots of red and squiggly lines

Comment: Sorry, I mean when you calculate that sum _manually_ with the rounded values you place in `netAmountA` and 'netAmountB`, you get the rounding error :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough rep points to add a comment to Jane S' answer, but I agree with her.

You round too early. If you had simplified your code:

```
decimal wallet = 5353.66m;
decimal gusset = 1351.54m;            
decimal netAmountA = wallet/1.2m;
decimal netAmountB = gusset/1.2m;
decimal vatAmount = wallet + gusset - (wallet/1.2m + gusset/1.2m);
Console.WriteLine(netAmountA + netAmountB + vatAmount);
```

you would have been rewarded with a much nicer result: 6705,2000000000000000000000000

(alternatively replace the last line with `Console.WriteLine("result: {0:C}", netAmountA + netAmountB + vatAmount);`)

Comment: Now you should be able to add comments :)

Comment: I still haven't managed to get it working. Perhaps if you could explain it in a different way. Thank you

Comment: Well, whip out your trusty old calculator, divide 5353.66 by 1.2. The result is 4461.3833333333333333333333333333.

In your original post, you then, for some inexplicable reason, decide to call Math.Round() asking it to chop off everything after the second decimal.

You then do this to the other netAmount as well, reducing accuracy further. Your code, as posted, is asking for trouble.